# How to fix the BadTokenException error in android??

Tags: android, exception, android-windowmanager

I have developed an application in which i have 4 tabs A,B,C,D. Each of the Tab contains an Activity. In the fourth tab D I have added an ActivityGroup in which I am having 3 more Activities X,Y,Z.In the fourth Tab where I have added the activity group I am getting StackOverflow error.Please help me out in fixing this error.

this is my stackTrace:--

```
06-30 18:22:26.521: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1293): android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.app.LocalActivityManager$LocalActivityRecord@62668448 is not valid; is your activity running?
06-30 18:22:26.521: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1293):     at android.view.ViewRoot.setView(ViewRoot.java:468)
06-30 18:22:26.521: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1293):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:177)
06-30 18:22:26.521: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1293):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:91)
06-30 18:22:26.521: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1293):     at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:424)
06-30 18:22:26.521: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1293):     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:239)
06-30 18:22:26.521: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1293):     at android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.show(AlertDialog.java:802)
06-30 18:22:26.521: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1293):     at android.widget.Spinner.performClick(Spinner.java:257)
06-30 18:22:26.521: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1293):     at android.view.View.onTouchEvent(View.java:4179)
06-30 18:22:26.521: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1293):     at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3709)
06-30 18:22:26.521: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1293):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:852)
06-30 18:22:26.521: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1293):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
06-30 18:22:26.521: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1293):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
06-30 18:22:26.521: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1293):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
06-30 18:22:26.521: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1293):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
06-30 18:22:26.521: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1293):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
06-30 18:22:26.521: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1293):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1659)
06-30 18:22:26.521: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1293):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1107)
06-30 18:22:26.521: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1293):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2061)
06-30 18:22:26.521: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1293):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1643)
06-30 18:22:26.521: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1293):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
06-30 18:22:26.521: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1293):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
06-30 18:22:26.521: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1293):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1659)
06-30 18:22:26.521: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1293):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1107)
06-30 18:22:26.521: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1293):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2061)
06-30 18:22:26.521: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1293):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1643)
06-30 18:22:26.521: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1293):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
06-30 18:22:26.521: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1293):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
06-30 18:22:26.521: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1293):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1659)
06-30 18:22:26.521: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1293):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1107)
06-30 18:22:26.521: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1293):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2061)
06-30 18:22:26.521: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1293):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1643)
06-30 18:22:26.521: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1293):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
06-30 18:22:26.521: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1293):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
06-30 18:22:26.521: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1293):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1659)
06-30 18:22:26.521: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1293):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1107)
06-30 18:22:26.521: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1293):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2061)
06-30 18:22:26.521: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1293):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1643)
06-30 18:22:26.521: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1293):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
06-30 18:22:26.521: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1293):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
06-30 18:22:26.521: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1293):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1659)
06-30 18:22:26.521: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1293):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1107)
06-30 18:22:26.521: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1293):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2061)
06-30 18:22:26.521: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1293):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1643)
06-30 18:22:26.521: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1293):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
06-30 18:22:26.521: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1293):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
06-30 18:22:26.521: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1293):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
06-30 18:22:26.521: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1293):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
06-30 18:22:26.521: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1293):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
06-30 18:22:26.521: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1293):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
06-30 18:22:26.521: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1293):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1659)
06-30 18:22:26.521: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1293):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow
```

THIS IS THE WAY I AM CONSTRUCTING THE TABS-------

```
Resources res = getResources();   
TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();  // The activity TabHost
TabHost.TabSpec spec;  // Reusable TabSpec for each tabO
Intent intent;  // Reusable Intent for each tab

// Create an Intent to launch an Activity for the tab (to be reused)

intent = new Intent().setClass(this,FirstActivity.class);
spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tab_First");
spec.setIndicator("First",res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab));
spec.setContent(intent);      
tabHost.addTab(spec);

// 2nd tab
intent = new Intent().setClass(this,SecondActivity.class);
spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tab_Second");
spec.setIndicator("Second",res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab));
spec.setContent(intent);
tabHost.addTab(spec);

//3rd Tab
intent = new Intent().setClass(this,ThirdActivity.class);
spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tab_Third");
spec.setIndicator("Third",res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab));
spec.setContent(intent);
tabHost.addTab(spec);        

// 4th tab    
intent = new Intent().setClass(this,FourthActivity.class);
spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tab_Fourth");
spec.setIndicator("Fourth",res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_create));
spec.setContent(intent);
tabHost.addTab(spec);           

tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
```

Comment: providing only the LogCat messages will not be enough information to answer your question.  show the relevant code for the tab and how you are constructing all of your tabs.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any [Stackoverflow Error](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/StackOverflowError.html) (are you sure you know what a Stackoverflow is?)... your problem is that somehow you are trying to display a dialog inside an activity that is already finished or is not in the foreground. At least, that's what we can infer from your logcat trace.

Comment: Actually after certain number of operations it's throwing the exception.Last time the exception was thrown when i tried to click the spinner.But I tried to find out the cause of the exception..sometimes it shows the android.view.windowmanager badtokenexception and sometimes the StackOverflow Exception.

Comment: Ok, so, in Java (and thus Android), a StackOverflow exception is usually shown when you are invoking a method recursively. For instance, this cause a StackOverflow exception: `void name(){name();}`. So take a look at your code and see if somehow you are doing something like that.

Comment: Hi Cristian! Actually I am having this problem in the fourth tab where I am navigating through a series of activities. I am navigating something like this.... FourthActivity->X and Y.  then from Y-> FourthActivity and then X->Z , Z-> FourthActivity. I am not able to understand where actually I am going wrong coz sometimes the exception is thrown even while drawing the view.

Answer (score 1):

As @Cristian has mentioned, i can also say you are trying to display a dialog inside an activity or referring context of the current activity, but whenever you are supposed to use context while using ActivityGroup with Tabs, at that time you need to use `getParent()` to get context of parent view.

While displaying dialog, you need a parent activity's context:

```
  // define at Global level and use it inside the activity whenever you want to refer                
  //activity context;
  private Activity activity;  

  //Write this inside onCreate() method.        
  activity = getParent();
```

Now, whenever you are supposed to refer context, then use this activity context value.

Comment: Hi Paresh!! I tried it out but still the problem is ther..I am able to open the dialog but again after few operations it's throwing the StackOverflowException.

Comment: You are setting FourthActivity.class in 4th Tab, so is it a group class or single activity class?

Comment: Paresh it is an ActivityGroup.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common error that can be fixed using 'getApplicationContext' instead of 'this' in your dialog. See also [FATAL EXCEPTION: main](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6493843/fatal-exception-main/6493937#6493937). The error occurs when you (from the dialog) attempt to use the context of the activity that started the dialog, when that activity is no longer in the foreground.

Answer (score -1):

where you have create the tabs make a static context and use any where in activity where you want to create the dialog box